# Enforce minimum spacing between non-zero elements in array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, poisson

I'm trying to generate an array of zeroes and ones where the spacing between ones is Poisson-distributed.

I believe this code does the trick:

```
import numpy as np

dt = 0.05
n_t = 500 / dt  # desired length of array
r = 100
spike_train = (np.random.rand(n_t) < r * dt).astype(int)
```

However, I'd also like to enforce a minimum spacing between ones -- such as a minimum of two zeroes between any two ones.

What's an efficient way to do this?

Comment: maybe i can generate a shorter array ... and then zero-pad in between array elements?  this is a half-baked idea right now ....

Comment: One idea that come to my mind is to place `1, 0, 0` instead of just `1`, and you could achieve this in this way: `spike_train = ([1,0,0] if n else [0] for n in np.random.rand(n_t) < r * dt).astype(int)` and then flaten the list

Comment: @HemersonTacon yeah, i guess you're thinking similar to how i am .... but in your case you don't get an array of length `n_t`, which is what's desired.  i should clarify what `n_t` and the other variables mean.  in your case the actual length would vary from run to run.

Comment: The 2 minimum zeros when occur should also count in the total zeros that the distribution should approximate to, right?

Comment: @HemersonTacon yeah, that's the thing i haven't found a solution for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reasonably efficient way. It works by (1) first ignoring the minimum wait. (2) computing inter-event-times (3) adding the minimum wait,(4) going back to absolute times discarding events that have been shifted out the right end. It can create 10**7 samples in less than a second.

```
import numpy as np

def train(T, dt, rate, min_wait):
    p = dt*rate
    # correct for minimum wait
    if p:
        p = 1 / (1 / p - min_wait) 
    if p > 0.1:
        print("warning: probability too high for approximation to be good")
    n = int(np.ceil(T/dt))
    raw_times, = np.where(np.random.random(n) < p)
    raw_times[1:] += min_wait - raw_times[:-1]
    good_times = raw_times.cumsum()
    cut = good_times.searchsorted(n)
    result = np.zeros(n, int)
    result[good_times[:cut]] = 1
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought in this (not so elegant) logic to keep the distribution:

```
def assure_2zeros(l):

    for idx in range(len(l)):
        # detect the problem when the ones are adjacent
        if l[idx] == 1 and l[idx+1] == 1:
            # check forward for a zero that could be realocated to split the ones
            for i in range(idx+2, len(l)-1):
                # check to not create other problems
                if l[i] == 0 and l[i-1]== 0 and l[i+1]== 0:
                    del l[i]
                    l.insert(idx+1, 0)
                    break
            # if doesnt found any zero forward, check backward
            else:
                for i in range(idx-1, 0, -1):
                    if l[i] == 0 and l[i-1]== 0 and l[i+1]== 0:
                        del l[i]
                        l.insert(idx+1, 0)
                        break

        # detects the problem when there are one zero between the ones
        if l[idx] == 1 and l[idx+2] == 1:
            for i in range(idx+3, len(l)-1):
                if l[i] == 0 and l[i-1]== 0 and l[i+1]== 0:
                    del l[i]
                    l.insert(idx+1, 0)
                    break
            else:
                for i in range(idx-1, 0, -1):
                    if l[i] == 0 and l[i-1]== 0 and l[i+1]== 0:
                        del l[i]
                        l.insert(idx+1, 0)
                        break

    return l
```

Note that when there is two adjacent ones, the first if will insert a zero between them, then it will enter in the second if and the second zero will be inserted. However, it fails when there is two or one zero at the very end or begining of the list. More conditions could be added in the if statements, but for your case there is plenty of zeros and I think it could work.